# Use Views for Search

Tags: 7, views, search

You can use Views for search results by using "Search Keywords" as a Contextual Filter.

This works fine when you search using a single word. But when entering multiple words with spaces, you don't get the correct results (usually no results).

Any idea how to solve this huge problem?

Comment: Sorry, but link-only questions are not really good. They will cease to be readable once they are answered (unless you want to keep that site buggy forever? But if so, why would you ask?) and as such are of no use for future visitors. So why should we work for you, for free? We may be willing to work for free for Drupal community, but not for a single person.

Comment: FYI: it works when you add and(&) operator check this http://www.shoejunks.nl/search?keys=Rachel&Zoe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for an answer for hours... I thought I made a mistake, but it seems there is a bug in the Views module! I guess I'm not the only one with this problem, so I'd like to share the sollution I finally found.

Make a custom module and add these lines of code:

```
function mymodulename_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  // Fix bug where multiple terms in search index filter returns no results
  if (isset($query->relationships['search_total'])
      && !empty($query->fields['score'])
      && empty($query->fields['score']['table'])) {
    $query->fields['score']['table'] = 'search_total';
  }
}
```

The sollution was found here: https://drupal.org/node/1948510